# python program stucks while trying to make a get http request

Tags: web-scraping, python-requests, python-3.6, bad-request

I want to send an HTTP request, a `GET` one, to [sahibinden](https://sahibinden.com/en) by using [requests library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/).

Any browser can do this task and I want to stimulate it using python. Here is my code:

```
from requests import get

headers = {
    'Host': 'www.sahibinden.com',
    'User-Agent':  'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.1',
    'Cookie': 'MS1=https://www.sahibinden.com/category/en/real-estate; vid=668; cdid=FareXv19cbCTdery5b49a52a; MDR=20180606; __gfp_64b=bDEm7fs0Wb7A.7Rrxx3Vc8KWiV2tqUPA6HKxPqxMzzD.Q7; __gads=ID=c46feb38656fe808:T=1531553074:S=ALNI_MZsbdGGUmPpzuJMK0RROk--kk0Y9w; _ga=GA1.2.2138815818.1531553081; nwsh=std; showPremiumBanner=false; showCookiePolicy=true; userLastSearchSplashClosed=true; MS1=https://www.sahibinden.com/category/en/real-estate; st=a6abb06a0b0f9430ea7fdebd78bf1a15232062dddb59afb52b771d194a3529a1e30b6ca15b691061108084738973f686da6e51c3e00daf378',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
}
res = get(
    "https://www.sahibinden.com",
    headers=headers
)
print(res.status_code)
```

I tried to do what a browser does, so I copied all the headers a browser sets(headers can be seen in the code above)

Browser gets the response in less than 3 seconds and shows the website just fine, but what my program gets is:

```
requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.sahibinden.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=10)
```

how can I solve this problem?

Comment: what if you try    `https://www.sahibinden.com` in the get call?

Comment: @Adrian `www.sahibinden.com` causes errors. but using 'https://www.sahibinden.com' solves the problem .